# Remote Desktop from Windows 7 to XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

Can I remote desktop from Windows 7 64bit Pro to Windows XP 32bit Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but only Professional edition of XP and above.

You have to enable Remote Desktop through `Control Panel` > `System` > `Remote Desktop`.

From there you should be set to go.

If you need any extra help, Microsoft have an [article about it here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/getstarted/remoteintro.mspx).

If your machine is not running a Professional edition of XP, you can still use a large list of applications such as [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com), [Logmein](http://www.logmein.com) or [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) - just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may get a warning. You can safely ignore this. Don't be scared to try it. Still operates on same terminal services. Vista/7 just have newer versions and seem to 'talk' better, but XP x86 Pro will still work as a host.